# How Twilio is considering the same user in different Twilio Conversation services with respect to pricing?

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-conversations, twilio-javascript, twilio-sdk

We have the requirement to create multiple conversation services under Twilio console and each conversation service will be used with respective applications. Different conversation services will have the same users so I wanted to know How Twilio is considering the active users if the same active user is added in different conversation services. How is Twilio considering the same user in different Twilio Conversation services with respect to pricing? will it be considered the unique single user?

We have added unique users in two different conversation service however its SID is different. Is there any way to use same unique users in multiple conversation service?